# Authenticate Playwright tests with multiple roles only if necessary

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I am following this guide https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#multiple-signed-in-roles to authenticate multiple test users, save authenticated states and then reuse these states to speed up test execution (to do not go through login flow on every test). But I find that if I have large number of test users not always I need to authenticate with all of them.

For example if I run only smoke test suite with `npx playwright test --grep "Smoke"` only some users are used in this suite. My question - is there a way to tell playwright to authenticate only those users that will be used in tests?

Currently I store my users in json file, load the credentials, authenticate and store state:

```
import { test as setup, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import * as data from '@/source/testData/data.json';

const keys = Object.keys(data.users);
keys.forEach((key) => {
  const credentials = data.users[key as keyof typeof data.users];
  const userFile = `playwright/.auth/${credentials.username}.json`;

  setup(`Authenticate user ${credentials.username}`, async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('https://somerandomwebsite.com);
    await page.getByLabel('Username').fill(credentials.username);
    await page.getByLabel('Password').fill(credentials.password);
    await page.click('text=Submit');

    await expect(page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Profile' })).toBeVisible({ timeout: 30000 });
    await page.context().storageState({ path: userFile });
  });
});
```

And in test I use these states like this:

```
test.describe('Smoke tests', () => {
  test.use({ storageState: 'playwright/.auth/customer1.json' });

  test('add item to cart', async ({ page }) => {
    // Do some testing here
  });
});
```

But if I would have 100 test users and would like to run only this 'Smoke tests' Playwright would authenticate all 100 users and only then run this single test. Is there any way to configure Playwright to authenticate only necessary users?

Comment: Do you have 100 different user roles in Prod? How do they differ from each other?

Comment: I am working on a large system where user could have many different access rights - access only some features, can have different view and edit rights for different features, access only some areas, view and edit particular data and so on. So many different user configurations.

Comment: Then it's very expensive to test/maintain that kind of huge permutation of configuration on UI. I would find a lower lever like API where all kind of permutation/ combination can be tested cheaply in terms of test creation/execution/ maintenance cost.